# Share MVC Master Page using Virtual Directories

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I’ve created a VS 2013 solution with a Master project (includes master page and common files) and an Outage project.  I need to access the master files from the Master project in my Outage project.  The Master project will be the main/root site (WestSupport) and Outage will be a feature section of that site.  So the URL would look like http://WestSupport/ and http://WestSupport/Outage.  There will be many more feature sections.  Just trying to get 1 working.  We want to keep everything in separate projects so developers can independently work on and publish different features of the site.

In my local IIS I’ve created an IIS application for the Master project (as WestSupport) with Outage as a virtual directory under Master.  The main page for Master loads and when I click on the link to Outage it navigates to the expected URL, but I get a 403.14 error (Directory Browsing).  If I add Default.aspx page to Outage, it loads.  I’ve made several changes to the IIS configuration based on suggestions online, along with modifying the routing.  An abbreviated list of what I’ve tried already.

- Registered .NET framework. (even though it was already registered).
- Confirmed the App Pool was set to ASP.NET v4.0 Integrated.
- Installed HTTP Redirection in IIS.
- Created another Virtual Directory to Master under Outage.  (Desperation)
- Promoted Outage to an application.  Outage loads, but then I can’t access the Master files since its part of a different application.
- Added the following to web.config in both project roots.
  [image]

Here’s what IIS looks like.

[image]

Here’s the VS project with the Master RouteConfig.
[image]

Here’s the Routing for Outage.  You can tell I’ve been playing with various routes.
[image]

Is this even possible?  I was able to share the master page in Outage if I created a Reference Link, but this isn’t our ideal solution.  We’d really like to keep it completely separate.  This is my first MVC project and I’m no wiz when it comes to IIS.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure on this, but the ViewEngines use the VirtualPathProviders to location views.  I don't know if the VirtualPathProviders can access files outside the application root directory.  In either case, knowing about the VirtualPathProviders is probably the first step.

Comment: If you want to share views between projects, the correct way is to compile them into a class library using Razor Generator: https://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/

Comment: I'll check into VirtualPathProviders.  Hadn't run into that anywhere.  

As far as the Razor Generator...  Not sure if it matters that I'm using the ASPX engine?  And in order to access the Outage controllers in Master, I had to add a reference to Outage in Master.  I can't add a reference to Master now in Outage because it creates a circular reference.  I actually thought about embedding a Master dll in Outage, but I can't because of the existing reference.